# How to fix 'Exceeded 30 redirects' error with Beautiful Soup and Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm web-scraping an API directory in a jupyter notebook. My code works fine grabbing the `name`, `URL`, `category`, and `description`, until after running for a few minutes, and an error message pops up saying `TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects`.

This is my first time trying this, and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Here is my complete code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

d = {'key':'value'}
print(d)

d['new key'] = 'new value'
print(d)

API = {}
API_no = 0

while True:
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
    interfaces = soup.find_all('tr',{'class':['even','odd']})
    
    for interface in interfaces:
        api_title = interface.find('td',{'class':'views-field views-field-title col-md-3'}).text
        api_url = 'https://www.programmableweb.com' + interface.find('a').get('href')
        api_category_tag = interface.find('td',{'class':'views-field views-field-field-article-primary-category'})
        api_category = api_category_tag.text if api_category_tag else "N/A"
        ​
        interface_response = requests.get(api_url)
        interface_data = interface_response.text
        interface_soup = BeautifulSoup(interface_data,'html.parser')
        interface_description_tag = interface_soup.find('div',{'class':'api_description tabs-header_description'})
        interface_description = interface_description_tag.text if interface_description_tag else "N/A"
        
        
        API_no+=1
        API[API_no] = [api_title, api_url, api_category, interface_description]
        
        print('API Name:', api_title, '\nURL:', api_url, '\nAPI Category:', api_category, '\nDescription:', interface_description, '\n---')
    url_tag = soup.find('a',{'title':'Go to next page'})
    if url_tag.get('href'):
        url = "https://www.programmableweb.com" + url_tag.get('href')
        print(url)
    else:
        break
        
print('Total APIs:', API_no)
API_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(API, orient = 'index', columns = ['API Name', 'URL', 'API Category', 'Description'])
```

I expect the code to go through the 21,000 API's eventually but it stops because of the redirects error message. Any suggestions as to how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237672/python-toomanyredirects-exceeded-30-redirects)

Comment: What url is it trying to request when that error happens?