# Why am I getting a redirect loop with this python program?

Tags: python, python-requests, httprequest

I'm trying to get a url using python requests. `requests.get('https://google.com')` works fine but then I add my custom headers and get a redirect loop, why?

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en", 
    "Host": "google.com", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-63261f60-6a62c4934cad2e126b4bdd8c"
  }
s.get('https://google.com')
```

I then get this error:

```
raise TooManyRedirects(
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237672/python-toomanyredirects-exceeded-30-redirects

Comment: This is a question similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237672/python-toomanyredirects-exceeded-30-redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set Host to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

```py
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en", 
    "Host": "www.google.com", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-63261f60-6a62c4934cad2e126b4bdd8c"
  }
resp = s.get('https://www.google.com')
```

google server checks your header host, because it is not equal to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it said redirect to the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and because you never change it in your headers so get stuck in redirect loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s.get('https://google.com', allow_redirects=False)
```

Details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42238106/19209687